# Powershell: Adgroupmembers to csv, csv name adgroup

Tags: powershell, csv

i have to export all domain groups with their members to csv. So each group has to get their own csv. in this csv has to be all group members.

I think i know where the problem is: $group value is @{name=xyz} not xyz. Probably thats why  ADGroupMember -Identity isnt matching.

```
 $groups = (Get-ADGroup -filter {GroupScope -eq "DomainLocal"} |Select-Object name)
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Add-Content -Path ("C:\"+$group) -Value (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group)
    }
```

edit: code solved below. i would need help with adding users to each csv file. dunno how to look for them.

Comment: This is SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO common.... By using `Select-Object name` you receive an **object** with a property called `Name`. This is **NOT** a string and when you treat it like a string, the result is what you see. If you only want the **Value** of the property, do `Select-Object -ExpandProperty name`.

Comment: It's not working as well ;)

Comment: You should not simply edit your question with _"code solved below"_, but instead accept the answer that best solved you problem by clicking the large checkmark icon on the left of that answer. This way, nobody will ever find it if they have the same problem..,

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you need to get the string **value** of the property called `Name`, not an **object** that holds that property with value Name.

Then there is the problem of how you create the output file name, AND cmdlets `Add-Content`, `Set-Content` etc. are not meant to write CSV files. For that PowerShell has `Export-Csv` where you feed it the objects returned from `Get-ADGroupMember` in this case:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupScope -eq 'DomainLocal'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    # construct the output path for the csv file
    $csvOut = Join-Path -Path "C:\19158" -ChildPath ('{0}.csv' -f $group)
    # use Export-Csv to create a correct CSV file
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Export-Csv -Path $csvOut -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
}
```

An alternative would be to not use Select-Object at all, but loop through the objects returned from `Get-ADGroup` and use the `$_` [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#_)

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupScope -eq 'DomainLocal'" | ForEach-Object {
    # construct the output path for the csv file
    $csvOut = Join-Path -Path "C:\19158" -ChildPath ('{0}.csv' -f $_.Name)
    # use Export-Csv to create a correct CSV file
    $_ | Get-ADGroupMember | Export-Csv -Path $csvOut -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the first line like that

```
$groups = (Get-ADGroup -filter {GroupScope -eq "DomainLocal"}).name
```